# Cannot find new Remote Desktop interface that was here before

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Bear with me.

My boss has Windows 10 and he had a different interface for Remote Desktop than I have been used to for the last decade or so. Rather than a simple window, it had a kind of tile display, where you could save different remote connections under different names, along with all their parameters ( alias/nickname, IP address, resolution, etc). So after saving it once, you can in the future just double click on the connection to open it up with all the saved settings.

Now that’s all gone, replaced with the old interface, which has some bugs. (The laptop he is using is 4K and causes resolution problems.)

How do I get this “new interface” back? Is it a Microsoft interface or is it perhaps a Lenovo proprietary interface?

Answer (score 2):

He likely ran [Microsoft Remote Desktop Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989)

[image]